# faster InnoDB writes?

Tags: performance, mysql

I'm about to replace an old server with completely new hardware, but something strange happens.

- The *old machine* is an **AMD Athlon 64 X2 5600+ @ 1GHz** with **2 GB RAM** running Debian 4.0 **32bit** and 2x380 GB (or so) HDD in RAID1
- The *new machine* is an **Intel i7-3770 @ 3.4GHz** with **32 GB RAM** running Debian 6.0 **64 bit** with 2x3TB HDD in RAID1 (6Gbps SATA, 7200rpm)

When loading a SQL dump (see below) the new server is busy for about **32 minutes**! Being freshly installed, the server has nothing else to do. On the other hand, the *old* server takes *32% **less** time* even though it is busy with other things. **How can that be?**

Both machines have been installed using Debian minimal images and then packages have been installed as needed.

The [my.cnf settings of the old server](http://pastebin.com/MuqNAjNJ) and the [new server](http://pastebin.com/6UqFHeu7) both use `innodb_file_per_table` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`is much larger (16 GB vs 0.5 GB) on the new server.

Data about the SQL dump:

- loading a completely new database (`CREATE DATABASE`)
- 16 tables
- a single large table (about 1,2M rows / 240MB SQL data) that is slow
- InnoDB with foreign keys
- dump uses `LOCK TABLES "xxx" WRITE; ALTER TABLE "xxx" DISABLE KEYS;` (generated by `mysqldump`)

Any ideas how to speed up that thing?

**Update**

I noticed that the old machine uses a dedicated 50GB ext3 partition on `/var` while the new one has a 1TB ext4 root partition (including `/var`) and a 2TB ext4 on `/home`. MySQL data is at `/var/lib/mysql/` in both cases.

**Update 2**

Apparently it's the HDD that is handling small blocks slowly:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024 count=100 oflag=direct,sync
102400 bytes (102 kB) copied, 2.49824 s, 41.0 kB/s
```

The old server hits **1.1 MB/s** with the same test.

Larger blocks can be handled find by the new server:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024k count=100 oflag=direct,sync
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 7.11175 s, 14.7 MB/s
```

`hdparm` says that the write cache is on on both drives. A partition table alignment problem? See [my partition table](http://pastebin.com/SP8NMjjk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason for this and hopefully this will help others.

**ext4** had "barriers" enabled on that system causing small writes to become very slow. Such writes are normal for database files.

Disabling barriers boosts performance and the same SQL dump is loaded in ~8 minutes (that's 4 times faster).

```
mount -o remount,barrier=0 /
```

Disabling barriers comes with fs integrity downsides, so think about that first...

Answer (score 0):

You have this line at the end of your new config file:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Assuming the files in there are the same as these: https://github.com/biapy/howto.biapy.com/tree/master/mysql, that means it is adding these settings (amongst others) which you might want to review:

base-optimisations.cnf:

```
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sync_binlog = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the include dir just contains the Debian standard `mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf` which contains `[mysqld_safe] syslog` and does not activate binary logging. `/var/log/mysql` is an empty dir on that machine.

Comment: Could it be that you've switched from 10K/15K SCSI/SAS drives to 7200RPM SATA drives? What RAID controllers do the machines have? What's the status of write caching on either array? Is there anything else running on the new machine that could be writing to the disk at the same time? Try the command iotop if your system supports it.

Comment: old HDD are SAMSUNG HD401LJ (7200rpm SATA 300), new HDD are Samsung ST3000DM001-9YN1. Both machines use Linux software RAID. When not importing the SQL dump the machine is completely IDLE (CPU 99.8% idle, load 0.01, pratically no disk I/O as per iotop). OTOH, the *old* machine is typically at load values 1 to 3 with CPU ~75% idle. Don't know how to check the write caching status..?

Comment: Run hdparm -W /dev/(your drive here). You can toggle write caching with hdparm -W 1 /dev/... or hdparm -W 0 /dev/..., but in any case it's probably already on and I don't think it would cause such a performance hit. Hopefully someone else has some other ideas.

Comment: write cache was already on: `/dev/sda: write-caching =  1 (on)`. Please notice my two updates in the question. Thanks.